# Install Postfix using Mailutils on Ubuntu 19.04 server for sending out mail only

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, webserver, mailx

I followed this tutorial: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

I'm trying to setup a send only mail from my Ubuntu 19 server. I followed the guide above and tried to install mailutils using:

```
apt install mailutils
```

It installed something but I'm not sure what as the `mailutils` command doesn't work as seen here:

[image]

[image]

I then installed via the following command:

```
apt install libmailutils-dev
```

That worked as `mailutils` command now runs, but I didn't get a GUI interface to select like how the guide shows it:

[image]

- What do I need to do now since the Postfix install GUI didn't popup according to the guide?
- Also is it an issue if I installed `mailutils` and then `libmailutils-dev`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `dpkg-reconfigure postfix` to see the wizard/GUI

Comment: Which gave me `dpkg-query: package 'postfix' is not installed and no information is available`. (Ubuntu 20.04) Use `apt install postfix` then.

Answer (score 0):

`mailutils` + `postfix` is described in quite a few tutorials, so in case someone else has the same problem:

The Ubuntu package changed.
In 18.04 `mailutils` still included `default_mta` (which is `postfix`) as a *dependency*, therefore it was installed with it.
From 19.10 it is only a *recommended* package.

The Changelog says:

```
mailutils (1:3.5-2) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Relax the dependency on a MTA to a recommendation.
    Thanks for the suggestion, - (closes: #916992).
```

https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/m/mailutils/mailutils_3.7-2.1/changelog

18.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mailutils
19:10: https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/mailutils
20.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mailutils

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20 postfix is not installed automatically, so we must do it:

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo DEBIAN_PRIORITY=low apt install postfix`

see [How To Install and Configure Postfix on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-20-04) for more details